# Regex for pattern

Tags: c#, regex

selecting only string that starts with ##### and ends with **mysig**. In between this two anything is allowed but not html tags. 
string s="##### anything **mysig** anthing ##### anything **othersig** anything ##### anything **mysig**";

one ending in **othersig** should not get selected

Here is what i was looking for

string str="##### anything here /**My(sig_nature)**/ anything here ##### anything here /**Notmine(sig_nature)**/ anything goes here ##### anything here /**My(sig_nature)**/ ";

what i wanted was all the text that starts with ##### and ends with /**My(sig_nature)**/

foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(str,@"[#]{5}.*/**My(sig_nature)**/"))
Console.WriteLine(match.Value.toString());

Comment: Can you post the regex you tried?

Comment: Is this a disguised html-parsing-with-regex question?

Comment: "^[#]{5}.*\b(mysig\b)$ . this extracts the entire string .. i want to extract only string that ends with mysig. More over there should not be any html tags in between ##### and mysig

Comment: So the pattern may also not contain `#####` then?

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
Regex.IsMatch(strInput, @"^#####[^<>]+mysig$");
```

explanation:

```
^         the beginning of the string

#####     '#####'

\.+       '.' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))

mysig     'mysig'

$         before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Comment: doesn't work. ^[#]{5}.*(mysig)$. I want my signature at the end. signature is say "Name"

Comment: Can you mention some valid and invalid input strings?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (a lot of guesswork went into this):

```
#####(?:(?!mysig|#####)[^<>])*mysig
```

This matches from `#####` to the closest `mysig` it can find, but only if there are no `#####` and no angle brackets in-between (and thus no HTML tags).